# Multiple If Condition,

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Hi I have this formula for multiple If condition how ever if my data is 85% the outcome is always 1.5 Should be 1.75 also with 92.54% outcome is 1.75 should be 2.25

```
100.00%         =3
97.00%-99.00%   =2.75
94.00%-96.00%   =2.5
91.00%-93.00%   =2.25
90.00%          =2
77.00%-89.00%   =1.75
64.00%-76.00%   =1.5
51.00%-63.00%   =1.25
40.00%-50.00%   =1
27.00%-39.00%   =0.75
14.00%-26.00%   =0.5
1.00%-13.00%    =0.25
0.00%           =0
```

My Formula

```
=IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3=100%, "3",
 IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=99%, "2.75",
 IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=96%, "2.5",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=93%, "2.25",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3=90%, "2",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=89%, "1.75",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=76%, "1.5",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=63%, "1.25",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=50%, "1",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=39%, ".75",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=26%, ".5",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=13%, ".25",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=0%, "0")))))))))))))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and put the comment into the body of the post. Use three backticks `\`\`\`` before and after your code so it appears formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a LOOKUP instead of nesting IFs in a situation like this to save you having to refer back to the target cell multiple times:

```
=lookup('TR&OD 2023'!D3,{{0%;1%;14%;27%;40%;51%;64%;77%;90%;91%;94%;96%;100%},{"0";".25";".5";".75";"1";"1.25";"1.5";"1.75";"2";"2.25";"2.5";"2.75";"3"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Formula, you've got :

```
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=89%, "1.75",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=76%, "1.5",
```

with a value of 85%, the condition `85% >= 89%` is not true, so it goes to the next condition :
`85% >= 76%` which is true, so it returns 1.5

The thing is your formula doesn't correspond to the rules stated above. What you'll want is this :

```
=IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3=100%, "3",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=96%, "2.75",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=94%, "2.5",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=91%, "2.25",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3=90%, "2",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=77%, "1.75",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=64%, "1.5",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=51%, "1.25",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=40%, "1",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=27%, ".75",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=14%, ".5",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=1%, ".25",
IF('TR&OD 2023'!D3>=0%, "0")))))))))))))
```